# Tapped thread maximum load

Tags: aluminum, threads

I am building a stair from aluminium to go to my basement, the stair sides-plates are made from 10mm thick aluminium AWS 5454.

I am planning to tap M10 thread into this plate. To avoid the step slipping against the stair sides a tension of 715N is required. The bolt material is A2-70.

But will this aluminium thread be able to hold this load? How do you calculate this?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: It's not usually recommended to use Stainless Steel Fasteners in direct contact with Aluminium, due to the risk of Galvanic Corrosion - you *might* be OK since it's indoors in a dry environment, but I would still take precautions to add a boundary layer between the two materials

Comment: What Thread Depth/Engagement do you have? Is your step supported from both sides? Can you provide a diagram showing how the step will actually be loaded/supported? "I will need to load my bolt with 715N" is a bit vague for me...

Comment: My step is supported on both side, I determinated a maximum step load, divided it by 4 bolts (no of bolts to hold the step) and used a friction coefficient of 0.75. this is the force required on the bolt to avoid shear. The thread depth is 10mm minus the small chamfer so lets say 9mm.

Comment: ^See? You meant a *tension* of 715N would prevent the stair from slipping against the wall? I read it the first time as, assuming the stair has slipped and is now resting on the bolt in single shear, the bolt needed to withstand 715N of shear... Pictures are worth 1,000 words, diagrams are worth 10,000.

Comment: And I know I'm still not getting into answering the question, but *how* did you determine that maximum step load? Does that take into account dynamic loads such as running up the stairs, or thumping them whilst carrying a heavy box?

Comment: Don't divide it by 4 bolts. That would work only if the load is centered, so the most optimistic scenario. If the load is placed above one of the bolts it will carry almost the entire load.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I Did a FEA on the design and this resulted in a minor bend 0.2mm in the step. Also I determinated this load taking my weight and the maximum weight of the appliance required in the basement. 100kg. But I would not be able to carry this by myself but maybe i will go exercise in the future ;)

Comment: @SF. you would suggest divide it by 4? Also, when you walk a single person stair don't you walk mostly centered? I do..

Comment: @JonathanRSwift what bolt material would you suggest then? Galvanized steel is also no OK?

Comment: @Mech_Engineer: Your weight standing still, not taking a heavy step from some 5 inches above? Also, when I walk, I place my left leg left of center, right leg right of center. If there's an obstacle, say, some box on the step, I step to the other side. And when I lose my balance, I place my feet wherever they could help me prevent falling, and as hard as necessary to prevent me from falling. You do NOT calculate structure durability for the 'best case' scenario. You do it for worst case and add a safety margin on top of that!

Comment: @Mech_Engineer - I'd use 'BZP' (bright zinc plated) screws, probably. See https://www.hunker.com/12502151/screws-compatible-with-aluminum for a good rundown on different options

Comment: @SF. I understand, but I say this load as it is a load where the displacement is nihil. there is still margin, the MPA in the von mises stress calculation is about 3x below the max allowed for the material. (taken a safety factor on the max MPA in account already)

Answer (score -1):

As a first estimate, assuming the stair is straight and runners are equally spaced:

We assume each step is populated with one person going down and multiply the 200kg by 3 which is not too conservative a factor of safety, 600kg per step.

say we have a ratio of 18cm riser to 31cm runner of each step we get an angle of

$\ alpha = arctan 18/31 = 30\ degree$

We do a first attempt at designing the stringer as a uniformly loaded horizontal beam and then multiply the depth by cos(30) = 0.86

Assuming the horizontal projection of the length of the flight of stairs as L we have this moment,

$M = \frac {1980\times l^2} {8} \  \ $ for a simply supported beam.

Assuming allowable tensile strength of alum 2000kg-cm^2

$ M = \sigma\times S \ and \ S= bh^2/6   $

$ M = 2000\times 1\times h^2/6 $

All you need is plug L , the length and you have the h of your aluminum beam.

Later you check with your local code and refine the loads, dynamic safety factor of potential several people running down the stairs scaping a fire, etc.

This is just to give a sense of rough idea, otherwise this member has to be checked for longitudinal forces like column, local buckling, torsion, etc.

Comment: The question is about the holding power of a tapped 10mm Al plate. Can it hold M10 bolts torqued to give 715  N of tension?